# TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['int', 'str']

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, smote

I already referred the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406720/labelencoder-typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-float-and-str), [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/issues/759) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47655813/oversampling-smote-for-binary-and-categorical-data-in-python). Don't mark it as duplicate.

I am working on a binary classification problem where my dataset has categorical and numerical columns.

However, some of the categorical columns has a mix of numeric and string values. Nontheless, they only indicate the category name.

For instance, I have a column called `biz_category` which has values like `A,B,C,4,5` etc.

I guess the below error is thrown due to values like `4 and 5`.

Therefore, I tried the belowm to convert them into `category` datatype. (but still it doesn't work)

```
cols=X_train.select_dtypes(exclude='int').columns.to_list()
X_train[cols]=X_train[cols].astype('category')
```

And my data info looks like below

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 683 entries, 21 to 965
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column                                           Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------                                           --------------  -----   
 0   Feature_A                                        683 non-null    category
 1   Product Classification                           683 non-null    category
 2   Industry                                         683 non-null    category
 3   DIVISION                                         683 non-null    category
 4   biz_category                                     683 non-null    category
 5   Country                                          683 non-null    category
 6   Product segment                                  683 non-null    category
 7   SUBREGION                                        683 non-null    category
 8   Quantity 1st year                                683 non-null    int64   
dtypes: category(8), int64(1)
```

So, after dtype conversion, when I try the below SMOTENC, I get an error

```
print("Before OverSampling, counts of label '1': {}".format(sum(y_train == 1)))
print("Before OverSampling, counts of label '0': {} \n".format(sum(y_train == 0)))
cat_index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
# import SMOTE module from imblearn library
# pip install imblearn (if you don't have imblearn in your system)
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE, SMOTENC
sm = SMOTENC(categorical_features=cat_index,random_state = 2,sampling_strategy = 'minority')
X_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
```

This results in an error as shown below

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\utils_encode.py
> in _unique_python(values, return_inverse)
> 134
> --> 135         uniques = sorted(uniques_set)
> 136         uniques.extend(missing_values.to_list())
>
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> C:\Users\SATHAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_31168/1931674352.py in
>
> 6 from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE, SMOTENC
> 7 sm = SMOTENC(categorical_features=cat_index,random_state = 2,sampling_strategy = 'minority')
> ----> 8 X_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
> 9
> 10 print('After OverSampling, the shape of train_X: {}'.format(X_train_res.shape))
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\imblearn\base.py in
> fit_resample(self, X, y)
> 81         )
> 82
> ---> 83         output = self.*fit_resample(X, y)
> 84
> 85         y* = (
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\imblearn\over_sampling_smote\base.py
> in *fit_resample(self, X, y)
> 511
> 512         # the input of the OneHotEncoder needs to be dense
> --> 513         X_ohe = self.ohe*.fit_transform(
> 514             X_categorical.toarray() if sparse.issparse(X_categorical) else X_categorical
> 515         )
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_encoders.py
> in fit_transform(self, X, y)
> 486         """
> 487         self._validate_keywords()
> --> 488         return super().fit_transform(X, y)
> 489
> 490     def transform(self, X):
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in
> fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
> 850         if y is None:
> 851             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
> --> 852             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
> 853         else:
> 854             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_encoders.py
> in fit(self, X, y)
> 459         """
> 460         self._validate_keywords()
> --> 461         self.*fit(X, handle_unknown=self.handle_unknown, force_all_finite="allow-nan")
> 462         self.drop_idx* = self._compute_drop_idx()
> 463         return self
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_encoders.py
> in _fit(self, X, handle_unknown, force_all_finite)
> 92             Xi = X_list[i]
> 93             if self.categories == "auto":
> ---> 94                 cats = _unique(Xi)
> 95             else:
> 96                 cats = np.array(self.categories[i], dtype=Xi.dtype)
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\utils_encode.py
> in _unique(values, return_inverse)
> 29     """
> 30     if values.dtype == object:
> ---> 31         return _unique_python(values, return_inverse=return_inverse)
> 32     # numerical
> 33     out = np.unique(values, return_inverse=return_inverse)
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\utils_encode.py
> in _unique_python(values, return_inverse)
> 138     except TypeError:
> 139         types = sorted(t.**qualname** for t in set(type(v) for v in values))
> --> 140         raise TypeError(
> 141             "Encoders require their input to be uniformly "
> 142             f"strings or numbers. Got {types}"
>
> TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or
> numbers. Got ['int', 'str']

Should I transform `y_train` into categorical as well? Currently, it is `int64`.

Help please

Comment: I think `SMOTENC` requires all the values in column to have uniform type. You can try converting the column `biz_category` to string type.

Comment: I mean all columns are of `category` type. SMOTENC can handle both categorical and numerical columns

Comment: Yes, It can handle categorical and numerical columns but each categorical/numerical column should have uniform data type. You can not have a column of mixed datatypes.

Comment: So, how do I make sure that all values are of same type. Meaning, `A`, `B`, `C` and `4`, `5`. How can I make them all uniform dat type? can help me

Comment: One option would be to re-encode the column for e.g using labelencoder so that each value has the uniform data type but in this case I guess simply changing the dtype to string would also work.

Comment: isn't `category` not datatype?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242192/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-the-great).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Cause of the problem

`SMOTE` requires the values in each categorical/numerical column to have uniform datatype. Essentially you can not have mixed datatypes in any of the column in this case your `biz_category` column. Also merely casting the column to categorical  type does not necessarily mean that the values in that column will have uniform datatype.

##### Possible solution

One possible solution to this problem is to re-encode the values in those columns which have mixed data types for example you could use lableencoder but I think in your case simply changing the `dtype` to `string` would also work.